# How to update database?

Tags: android, database

In my application I have a database. Although I can insert into the table successfully but I have problem in updating a field.

This code creates my table:

```
public final static String[] TABLES_NAME = {"general", "toprecipes", "favorites", "shoppinglist"};
//-- Columns of table: shopping list
    public final static String[] CLM_SHOPPINGLIST = {COLUMN_ID, "resepiId", "resepiName", "ingredient", "status"};
    private final String CRT_TBL_SHOPPINGLIST = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLES_NAME[3] + " (" + 
        CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[0] + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
        CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[1] + " TEXT," + 
        CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[2] + " TEXT," + 
        CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[3] + " TEXT," + 
        CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[4] + " TEXT"  + 
        ");";
```

I need that based on an event, set the status of item from "T" to "F" and vice versa.

For updating the database I have this code:

```
public void updateRecordStatus(String resepiName, String ingredientName, String status) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[4], status);

        database.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLES_NAME[3], cv, DatabaseHelper.CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[2] + "=" + resepiName + " AND " + DatabaseHelper.CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[3] + "=" + ingredientName, null);

        Log.i(TAG, "Status of ingredient '" + ingredientName + "' updated to '" + status + "' in table.");
    }
```

It seems everything is ok but I have no idea why — when I run the app and want to update, it crashes. Logcat shows these messages and points to `database.update(...)`:

```
08-07 08:08:03.289: I/Database(460): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "Bakar": syntax error
08-07 08:08:03.289: E/Database(460): Error updating status=T using UPDATE shoppinglist SET status=? WHERE resepiName=Terung Bakar Mediterrinean AND ingredient=2 biji lemon
08-07 08:08:03.289: W/dalvikvm(460): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-07 08:08:03.323: E/AndroidRuntime(460): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 08:08:03.323: E/AndroidRuntime(460): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Bakar": syntax error: , while compiling: UPDATE shoppinglist SET status=? WHERE resepiName=Terung Bakar Mediterrinean AND ingredient=2 biji lemon
08-07 08:08:03.323: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
08-07 08:08:03.323: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
08-07 08:08:03.323: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
08-07 08:08:03.323: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
08-07 08:08:03.323: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
08-07 08:08:03.323: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
08-07 08:08:03.323: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1671)
08-07 08:08:03.323: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1622)
08-07 08:08:03.323: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.astro.recipe.database.DBShoppingListHandler.updateRecordStatus(DBShoppingListHandler.java:107)
08-07 08:08:03.323: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.astro.recipe.activities.ShoppingList$2.OnCheckChangedListener(ShoppingList.java:90)
```

Any comments or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals must be enclosed in single quotes.

for example:

```
Where you='jox' AND authenticated='1'
```

keep in mind that you and authenticated are column names.

Comment: Thanks, for near 2 hours i was killing myself to find the problem. Thanks

Comment: Yes, i remember but i needed to wait 10 min and after that accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 database.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLES_NAME[3], cv, DatabaseHelper.CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[2] + "=" + resepiName + " AND " + DatabaseHelper.CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[3] + "=" + ingredientName, null);
```

With

```
 database.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLES_NAME[3], cv, DatabaseHelper.CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[2] + "= '" + resepiName + "' AND " + DatabaseHelper.CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[3] + "='" + ingredientName + "'", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
database.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLES_NAME[3], cv, DatabaseHelper.CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[2] + "='" + resepiName + "' AND " + DatabaseHelper.CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[3] + "='" + ingredientName+"'", null);
```

Try above

Put single quotes for strings.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
database.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLES_NAME[3], cv,
    DatabaseHelper.CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[2] + "=" + resepiName + " AND " +
    DatabaseHelper.CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[3] + "=" + ingredientName, null);
```

To:

```
database.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLES_NAME[3], cv,
   DatabaseHelper.CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[2] + " = ?" +
   " AND " + DatabaseHelper.CLM_SHOPPINGLIST[3] + " = ?",
   new String[]{resepiName, ingredientName});
```

This is the recommended way of using sql statements with parameters (using `?`)

Comment: These are sqlite query parameter's injector in android. By putting **?** in your query, the framework will automatically take care of single quotes issue, so you don't have to manually do the job. And its safe!   :)